# Как работает dynamic_cast

Tags: c++

Не совсем могу понять для чего нужен и как работает dynamic_cast

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Base() = default;
    virtual void p()
    {
        std::cout << "Base class";
    }

};
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Derived() = default;
    void p() override
    {
        std::cout << "Derived class";
    }

};
int main()
{
    Derived *b = new Derived();
    if (dynamic_cast<Base*>(b))
        b->p();
    return 0;
}
```

Разве не должно вывести *Base class*?

Comment: динамик каст = **работать с адресом b памяти как будто там лежит Base, а не Derived**, никакого фактического преобразования не происходит. Вы все так же работаете с настоящим объектом b(Derived), только теперь не можете вызывать те методы которые не объявлены в Base

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков а могу я как-то через `dynamic_cast` выполнить виртуальную функцию, которая принадлежит base? т.е, вывести `   virtual void p()
    {
        std::cout << "Base class";
    } `

Comment: Для этого даже каст не нужен https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853031/call-base-class-method-from-derived-class-object